# Div Sticks to Top when it Reaches Top and only Shows On Scroll Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a from in the middle of full screen hero section. When it reaches the top its position gets set to fixed and I have a simple script adding other classes to it. Like shrinking its height and adding a background etc...

What I want to do is when it reaches the bottom of the section#hero it then hides but displays when the user scrolls up.

Please refer to http://www.istockphoto.com/ their search container is doing exactly what I want to do with my sign up form for my landing page.

Thanks so much in advance!

Heres the section that contains the form:

```js
$(function() {
  // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
  var stickyHeaderTop = $('#grab').offset().top;
  var Innerwidth = window.innerWidth;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (Innerwidth >= 767) {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
        $('#grab').css({
          position: 'fixed',
          top: '0',
          left: '0',
          width: '100%',
          background: '#363451',
          paddingBottom: '15px'
        });
        $('form#signUp').css({
          marginTop: '15px'
        });
        $('form#signUp input').css({
          height: '45px',
          fontSize: '14px'
        });
        $('form#signUp button').css({
          height: '45px'
        });
      } else {
        $('#grab').css({
          position: 'relative',
          background: 'none'
        });
        $('form#signUp').css({
          marginTop: '25px'
        });
        $('form#signUp input').css({
          height: '65px',
          fontSize: '16px'
        });
        $('form#signUp button').css({
          height: '65px'
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
       h1 {
       margin-top: 100px;
       text-align: center;
       color: #363451;
       font-size: 45px;
       font-weight: 900;
   }

   h2 {
       text-align: center;
       color: #363451;
   }

   h3 {
       text-align: center;
       font-weight: 300;
       margin-top: 0px;
       color: #363451;
   }       

   h4 {
       font-size: 22px;
       font-weight: 300;
       margin-top: 0px;
       color: #363451;
   }

   p {
       color: #363451;
       padding: 25px;
       font-size: 16px;
   }

   .p-text {
       padding: 25px 0px !important;
       line-height: 1.8em;
       width: 80%;
   }

   .p-text-2 {
       padding: 0px !important;
       font-size: 18px;
   }

   .text-white {
       color: #ffffff !important;

   }

   .text-center {
       text-align: center;

   }

   .text-left {
       text-align: left;
   }

   .pad-master {
       padding: 10px 0;
   }

   .header-text {
       width: 55%;
       margin: 25px auto;
       text-align: left;
   }

   .subheader-text {
       width: 45%;
       margin: 15px auto 50px auto;
       padding: 0;
       text-align: center;
   }

   .header-bkg {
       padding: 10px 10px;
       background-color: #363451;
       width: 295px;
   }

   .header-bkg-2 {
       padding: 10px 10px;
       background-color: #363451;
       width: 440px;
   }

   .mainNavMenu {
       color: #363451;
       text-decoration: none;
       cursor: pointer;
       padding-bottom: 2px;
       border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
       transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
   }

   .mainNavMenu:hover {
       text-decoration: none;
       border-bottom: 2px solid #f630a5;
   }

   .mainFooterMenu {
       color: #fff;
       text-decoration: none;
       cursor: pointer;
       padding-bottom: 2px;
       border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
       transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
   }

   .mainFooterMenu:hover {
       color: #fff;
       text-decoration: none;
       border-bottom: 2px solid #f630a5;
   }

   .no-padding {
       padding: 0px !important;
       margin: 0px !important; 
   }
     section#hero {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-size: cover;
        background: url(../img/mainNavHero-fs.jpg) no-repeat top center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    #signUpContainer {
        width: 100%;
    }

    form#signUp {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 25px;
        z-index: 99;
    }

    form#signUp input {
        height: 65px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    form#signUp input.name {
        width: 100%;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        border-top: none;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: 0.5px solid #f2f2f2;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }

    form#signUp input.email {
        width: 100%;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        border-top: none;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-left: 0.5px solid #f2f2f2;
        border-right: none;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }

    form#signUp button {
        width: 100%;
        height: 65px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        background: #f630a5;
        border: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }

    input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    }

    form#signUp input:focus, form#signUp input:valid {
     box-shadow: none;
     outline: none;
     background-position: 0 0;
    }


    form#signUp input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder, form#signUp                         input:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: #db3095;
     font-size: 11px;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
     transform: translateY(-20px);
     visibility: visible !important; 
    }


    form#signUp button:hover {
        background: #db3095;  
    }

    .btnContainer {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 45px;
    }

    .btnContainer2 {
        margin-top: 45px;
    }

    a.primaryBtn {
        padding: 15px 25px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #363451;
        border: 2px solid #f630a5;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }

    a.primaryBtn:hover {
        background-color: #f630a5;
        border: 2px solid #f630a5;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    a.scrollBtn {
        padding: 15px 25px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #363451;
        border: 2px solid #f630a5;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }

    a.scrollBtn:hover {
        background-color: #f630a5;
        border: 2px solid #f630a5;
        color: #ffffff;
    }


    .infoContainer {
        background: #363451;
        padding: 25px 0px;
        margin-top: -50px;
       border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 8px 8px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="hero">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-padding">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <h1>HEADER<br>HEADER HEADER.</h1>
        <p class="subheader-text">Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff</p>
        <h3 class="header-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="grab" class="nav-down">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="signUpContainer">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 padding-toggle">
            <form id="signUp">
              <center>
                <div class="col-sm-3 no-padding">
                  <input id="name" class="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..." required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7 no-padding">
                  <input id="email" class="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email..." required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 no-padding">
                  <button>Sign Up</button>
                </div>
              </center>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 padding-toggle">
        <center>
          <div class="btnContainer">
            <a href="#" class="primaryBtn">Button</a>
          </div>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
    <section style="width:100vw;height:100vh;"></section>
```

Comment: Some styling of your code would help a lot :)

Comment: Sorry, I added some of the CSS. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

    $('#grab').slideUp();

}else{

    $('#grab').slideDown();

}
```

Note: I also added a higher `z-index` to your `#grab` container and removed the `height:100vh;` from `hero`.

https://jsfiddle.net/u5b514wu/

Comment: This is close but, I want the form to stick to the top when it reaches the top of the page like it already does then it acts like a header. After it reaches the bottom of the hero container it then hides until the user scrolls up. The user could start scrolling up at anytime further down and thats when it slides back down, but as soon as they scroll down again it hides again.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry - My explanation is bad. Please look at http://www.istockphoto.com/. Their search container in the middle of page does exactly what I want my sign up form to do.

Comment: This is it! I already have transitions on the form elements and grab container, instead of using .slideUp(); how could I use a class toggle like lets say a class that will use top: -(grab containers height)px; then on scroll down top: 0px; ?

Comment: $('#grab').addClass(); $('#grab').removeClass();